# How can I be sure that the expression is “minimal” SOP

Tags: boolean-expression

Reduce the expression `(w+x’+z)(w’+y+z’)(x+y+z)`to a minimum SOP

I’ve tried
(The original expression)

```
 = (z+wx+wy+x’y)(w’+y+z’)
 =w’z+yz+wxy+wxz’+wy+wyz’+w’x’y+x’y+x’yz’
 =w’z+yz+wxy+wxz’+wy+x’y+x’yz’
 =w’z+yz+wxy+wxz’+wy+x’z
 =w’z+yz+wy+wxz’+x’y
```

I’m not sure the result that I found is the “minimum” SOP. Is there any generalized way to get ‘minimum SOP from POS’ or ‘minimum POS from SOP’?

Comment: Is this really a programming problem, or a math problem (and thus should be on [the Math SE site](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour))?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing right now is called consensus theorem. It's not really supported in boolean algebra since it's a rare 3 term rule. Generally you would solve them with a K-Map. This can be reduced down another step using consensus theorem.

```
w'z+wy+wxz'+x'y
```

I am not totally sure if there's another step because it's not easy to find it.